# rqt_nav_view get a float division error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was just click on set pose and set goal and got this error.
How is this panel used? Set goal and set pose work on the rviz main panel.

```
viki:~$ rosrun rqt_nav_view rqt_nav_view 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_nav_view/nav_view.py", line 403, in mouseReleaseEvent
    map_p, quat = self.draw_position(e)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_nav_view/nav_view.py", line 354, in draw_position
    u = (v[0]/mag, v[1]/mag)
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78271/rqt_nav_view-get-a-float-division-error/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-09-10

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-09-22**:
@rnunziata  you closed the question as "the question is answered, right answer was accepted" but which one is the right answer?

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-09-23**:
I saw ticket so I closed it. Now I can see it was only for documentation enhancement. I will test it again and reopen if it has not been fixed by any recent upgrade.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-09-23**:
Problem still present. Question reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I opened an enhancement ticket for documentation https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/179

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0